# Android Linear Layout z-order animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-linearlayout

I have 3 element in a LinearLayout and I need to animate one of these.
When the animation starts, the element is not above the others, but It remain below.
I have already tried to use `bringToFront()` but It doesn't work (change order like doc says).
The element I need to animate "@id/ton" of this "vertical" layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapInfo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"   
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientonion="vertical"
    android:clipChildren="false" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"   
        android:background="@null"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/yourlogohere" /> 

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/ton"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
         /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

In this case the TextView is below of the WebView.
I use LinearLayout because I need that these element are 25/50/25% of height of device (I use weight xml attribute).

Answer (score -1):

The Z-Order is the index in the ViewGroup children array, if you want to change order then use removeView() and then addView() with the new index.

In the case of your LinearLayout if the view is added with index 0 it will be placed on top, instead if the view is added with `index == viewGroup.getChildrenCount()-1` it will be placed the lower.

And call `viewGroup.requestLayout();` later